# ESRI Javasacript API Legend digit: Modify Layer Names

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, labeling, legend

I am using the ESRI Javascript API Legend Digit in a map application and I would like to alter the display names as they appear in the legend.

I'm accessing map services with cryptic names like "Cel_clip2_V24" and I would like them to say something like "Local Farmer's Markets".

How do I control either the layer name or the legend label to achieve that?

Comment: What kind of services WMS?

Comment: please give the code of your legend instance .

Comment: the legend is the regular esri legend digit : https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/widget_legend.html

Comment: I'm working with both featureLayers and dynamicLayers

Comment: It appears as if the solutions are different for Feature and Dynamic layers.  There is another thread related to your questions that  you may want to look at. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68953/different-legend-properties-with-arcgis-api-for-javascript

Comment: Jeff May - It worked like a charm. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!